# Alguém consegue me ajudar? linguagem javascript

Tags: javascript

Define a função hojeSeJoga, que receba por parâmetro uma string que informe o día da semana. Esta função deve retornar"Hoje é dia de futebol! ! !" se parâmetro for "domingo", caso contrário deve retornar "Hoje não é dia de futebol :(".

Lembre-se que as variáveis e as strings devem ser escritas igual ao enunciado, respeitando os espaços e as exclamações.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hojesejoga

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    function hojeSeJoga (diaDaSemana){
if(diaDaSemana == 'domingo'){
  return 'Hoje é dia de futebol! ! !';
}else{
  return 'Hoje não é dia de futebol :(' ;
}
```

}

hojeSeJoga('domingo');